# How to approach workflows sharing some input data in snakemake?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have multiple snakemake workflows with some of them sharing some rule outputs - for example a rule to construct bwa/bowtie2 indexes and so on. How to manage this situation? Recently I found  [between workflow caching](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/caching.html), however there is a note in the bottom that this is an experimental implementation. More information about this is pretty scarce. My question is - are there any caveats or unsolved problems using the mentioned cache implementation? Or are there other ways that could save resources?

I plan to use it in HPC setting and running multiple workflows, while also with potentially other users running instances of same workflows. Thanks.

I tried two approaches. At first I kept workflows completely separated and independent, but this started to be a huge waste of time and disk space in some cases, human genome for example. Then I tried to manage it in a separate directory keeping outputs there and then linking to workflows. This proved soon to be erroneous and hard to manage, as workflows could use different tool versions or use different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It's doubtful that there is a single solution for this pattern. This is analogous to the situations that require code repetition in regular software development. The two extreme solutions are:

- isolate the common parts into a separate workflow that becomes a dependency for the other workflows;
- keep the common parts but protect the overlapping parts using `ancient` to avoid time-based recalculation.

While the first option might be tempting, just like strict DRY adherence, it might hurt workflow flexibility down the road. For example, if some adjustments are introduced into this workflow that alter compatibility with downstream workflows.

The second option might seem inefficient, however it can be better if the circumstances require independent development of these workflows, since less/no effort will be needed to synchronize changes across the workflows.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also please elaborate on `cache` functionality in snakemake? Do you have any experience with that? How it works in case of running multiple instances of the same workflow?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't worked with `cache` option, although it does look relevant!